# How to close Windows Portable Device IStream opened in Python / pythoncom / comtypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, wpd, comtypes, pythoncom

I'm using Windows Portable Device in python with pythoncom and comtypes.

I'm in trouble because when I request for WPD_RESOURCE_THUMBNAIL resource, some android devices returns a "square" thumbnail while the raw image has 16:9 format (or 4:3...).

Then I tried to request for WPD_RESOURCE_DEFAULT resource in order to get the thumbnail from the EXIF data: so no need to read the whole file, once I get the EXIF tag for the thumbnail I can stop the read and skip to next file.

I'm able to get the thumbnail from the EXIF for the very first file. On the second file I get stuck on the GetStream() method. It simply hang.
I suppose because the IStream from the previous call was not closed/disposed.

Have you any idea on how to force the Dispose / Close of this IStream?

This is what I do in code:

```python
optimalTransferSizeBytes, fileStream = resources.GetStream(
                    self.objectID,
                    WPD_RESOURCE_DEFAULT,
                    ctypes.c_ulong(0),
                    optimalTransferSizeBytes,
                    pFileStream
                )
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestion on this.

**EDIT**:
Since I found no other ways to interrupt the stream and release all the resources, I ended up reading the whole stream for WPD_RESOURCE_DEFAULT. It's a bit slower but it's safer because the application runs on big screens also and using the EXIF's thumbnail can lead to poor quality images on screen. So I decided to read the whole stream for WPD_RESOURCE_DEFAULT for this purpose and speed up code somewhere outside this point. 
Thank you @ShadowRanger for support.

Answer (score 1):

The `UnmanagedMemoryStream` type [has a `Dispose` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4), if your library exposes all the methods for you, a simple `fileStream.Dispose()` should work. To be safe, you'd want to either implement a context manager wrapper to allow the use of the `with` statement, or less Pythonically, but more simply, use a `try`/`finally`, e.g.:

```
optimalTransferSizeBytes, fileStream = resources.GetStream(
                    self.objectID,
                    WPD_RESOURCE_DEFAULT,
                    ctypes.c_ulong(0),
                    optimalTransferSizeBytes,
                    pFileStream
                )
try:
    ... do stuff with fileStream ...
finally:
    fileStream.Dispose()
```

Alternatively, you can [make your own context manager to perform disposal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def disposing(disposable):
    try:
        yield disposable
    finally:
        disposable.Dispose()
```

which would allow the slightly nicer code:

```
optimalTransferSizeBytes, fileStream = resources.GetStream(
                    self.objectID,
                    WPD_RESOURCE_DEFAULT,
                    ctypes.c_ulong(0),
                    optimalTransferSizeBytes,
                    pFileStream
                )
with disposing(fileStream):
    ... do stuff with fileStream ...
```

Comment: Note: I can't actually test this, so please let me know if it works for you. I can't find any documentation on using automatic disposal via `pythoncom` interfaces; if such a thing exists (likely handled via context management using `with` statements, a similar Python construct), that would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hi ShadowRanger, thank you for feedback. I tried using Dispose on fileStream but unfortunately It doesnt works. The type of fileStream is IStream . I retrieved this from IPortableDeviceResource.GetStream and this seems to not expose a Dispose method. It expose a Release method from IUnknown but using it in fileStream ends up in an "access violation writing" error without releasing the fileStream resource...

Comment: @shakraw: Gotcha. Guessing it doesn't expose `Close` either? What does it expose?

Comment: yes it doesn't expose Close either... It exposes a Release method from base interface IUnknown. Calling it do not free the resource at all. I also tried setting resource to None in order to remove references and called gc.collect also to do some cleaning but the resource is still alive in COM/Windows side and that blocks following calls to GetStream